# Is Crockford style Context Coloring implemented in any code editor?

Tags: javascript, editor, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

I watched a video from YUIConf 2012 in which Douglas Crockford gives a talk about implementing monads in JavaScript. In this talk he gives a code example that utilizes what he calls "Context Coloring" which throws out the idea of coloring by language syntax and introduces different colors for different levels of scope. Here is the link to that specific part of the video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dkZFtimgAcM#t=15m58s

**Is this context coloring scheme implemented by any code editor for JavaScript or any language?**

I use Sublime Text and this editor like every other code editor I have come across allows color to be applied to syntax. Im not sure if a plugin could solve this problem or if an editor would have to be designed from the ground up to allow this context coloring scheme.

Comment: I love this idea too, but I haven't found any answers other than 'rainbow coloring' that VIM and Emacs support. Looks like intellij has some interest in adding it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2390

Comment: DC: "[*I wish someone would build an editor for me that does this type of coloring*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dkZFtimgAcM#t=17m38s)" - seems not like someone has done it yet

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea from an a11y point of view.

Comment: Because, from an a11y point of view, syntax colouring was such a good idea ^o^//

In all seriousness, though, I can see this causing problems if the implementation is not perfect. With normal context colouring, literals are coloured, but the system doesn't try to guess the contents of variables and colour them appropriately. Context colouring would have to deduce the scope of variables, and the one time it guessed wrong might be pretty painful.

Good luck, though, I'd love to have a proven perfect context colouring plugin!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Feb-13th 2013 Crockford has added an experimental context coloring feature to JSLint.

https://plus.google.com/118095276221607585885/posts/FzKnHk96m2C

Answer (score 26):

I just watched his video on that, great stuff. Had to [**give it a try**](https://github.com/daniellmb/JavaScript-Scope-Context-Coloring), or checkout the project on GitHub https://github.com/daniellmb/JavaScript-Scope-Context-Coloring.

[image: JavaScript Scope Context Coloring]

Answer (score 12):

### Vim [(GitHub)](https://github.com/bigfish/vim-js-context-coloring):

[image]

### Emacs [(GitHub)](https://github.com/jacksonrayhamilton/context-coloring/):

[image: Screenshot of context coloring in Emacs.]

Answer (score 8):

There's a package for sublime now: https://github.com/mazurov/sublime-levels

It also has an online live demo at http://mazurov.github.io/eslevels-demo/

Answer (score 3):

BlueJ has it (1) - but then it also may not.  The context coloring for scope in javascript will certainly be more complicated than any other language such a java - which this editor works on.

The folks writing Brackets will probably do it eventually since they worship Crockford (2,3)

Why not join them in helping write it or at least tell them to?

Sources:

1) http://blogs.kent.ac.uk/mik/2010/05/bluej-3-0-whats-new/

2) https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/search?q=Crockford

3) http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/bracket-code-architecture.html

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say we on the Brackets team "worship" Crockford :-)  We do like linting in general, though.  We'd actually like to make it pluggable, and might even switch our own coding style to JSHint in the future.  There's a [user story](https://trello.com/card/3-jshint-support/4f90a6d98f77505d7940ce88/498) if you'd like to upvote it.

Comment: Nice, well if jsbin and jsfiddle can do it, I am sure the Adobe folks can!

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of. This would be great, but it would need a lexical analyzer specific to JavaScript and it would probably not work when there are any syntax errors.

Comment: This is really more appropriate as a comment.