# What IDE support semantic highlighting?

Tags: ide, syntax-highlighting, semantic-ui

After reading the [Coding in color: How to make syntax highlighting more useful](https://medium.com/@evnbr/coding-in-color-3a6db2743a1e) I'm unable to find a list of IDE that provide this feature (natively or with plugin).

Do you know of **editors have this feature?**

Comment: Related Is Crockford style Context Coloring implemented in any code editor? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15434680/802365

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking again I find the following editors/IDEs have support

- Atom.io

  - [language-javascript-semantic](https://atom.io/packages/language-javascript-semantic) by Philipp Emanuel Weidmann
- Emacs

  - [color-identifiers-mode](https://github.com/ankurdave/color-identifiers-mode) by Ankur Dave
  - [rainbow-identifiers](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-identifiers) by Fanael
- [kDevelop](https://zwabel.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/c-ide-evolution-from-syntax-highlighting-to-semantic-highlighting/)

  - Semantic Highlighting the original implementation/invention
- Sublime Text

  - [Sublime-Colorcoder](https://github.com/vprimachenko/Sublime-Colorcoder) by vprimachenko ;
- XCode

  - [Polychromatic](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/Polychromatic) by Kolin Krewinkel
- Vim

  - [Semantic Highlight](https://github.com/jaxbot/semantic-highlight.vim) by jaxbot
- Pycharm

  - [natively introduced in `2017.1` EAP](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/12/pycharm-2017-1-early-access-program-started/)