# How to align braces correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following code works but despite my best efforts I can't read it. 25 years of working with C++ appears to have left my brain incapable of decipering triple nested function declarations like this.

```js
app.directive('alertable', function(){
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        alert(attrs.alertable);
      });
     }
  };
});
```

I can just about read the following code but it doesn't work.

```js
app.directive
(
  'alertable',
  function()
  {
    return
    {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs)
      {
        element.bind
        (
          'click',
          function()
          {
            alert(attrs.alertable);
          }
        );
      }
    };
  }
);
```

The issue is that in Javascript for certain keywords the interpreter performs automatic semicolon insertion. The 'return' statement in the above code passage is one case where this occurs. The code will execute if the '{' following the return is on the same line as the return, otherwise it will fail.

In other words, Javascript, like Go, is one of those languages where despite being brace limited it is also whitespace dependent and just the presence or absence of whitespace is enough for the code not to compile.

In Javascript what is the best workaround for this that enables the correct alignment of braces on the same column?

Comment: If you can't read the former version, you can always make it less complex. `var foo = ...; return { bar: foo }`…

Comment: it is forbidden in javascript to have a new line char between return and its argument, just put the bracket on same line: `return {`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882241/is-crockford-style-context-coloring-implemented-in-any-code-editor this type of syntax highlighting should help. it is based on level of nesting rather than syntax

Comment: This is more opinion than anything else. I'd follow conventional JS styles--it's what you'll see most in the wild, e.g., the AirBnB JS guide. Plus if anyone has to deal with your code they'll thank you to stick with the norms. Nested functions are the norm so you'll need to be able to grok them, but pulling them out into named functions works the best, and they're easier to test in isolation.

Comment: I'd add that learning how to unlearn is just as valuable as learning how to learn. You had 25yrs of one paradigm--it will take time to adjust.

Comment: force yourself to get used to it. this is how it should be done. anyway, it's not a question for `stackoverflow`

Comment: @Neutrino I didn't say not to ask it. I said it's not for stackoverflow. There are many other stackexchange communities for such discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't use anonymous object literals as return values, bind it to a name instead. This isn't the only case where JavaScript ASI will byte you, but its probably the most common. So your original code will work fine with one minor change:

```
app.directive
(
  'alertable',
  function()
  {
    var foo = 
    {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs)
      {
        element.bind
        (
          'click',
          function()
          {
            alert(attrs.alertable);
          }
        );
      }
    };
    return foo;
  }
);
```

FWIW, I'm a JavaScript dev who sometimes works on porting C/C++ code via emscripten and I find it difficult to read GNU style after years of K&R.

Comment: This is what I'm doing at the minute. Do you know of any cases where Javascript's whitespace significance would cause this strategy to fail?

Comment: @Neutrino JS has almost no whitespace significance. The return issue is almost the only place it will ever be an issue, and it's a trivial issue to overcome--just don't put a return on a line by itself if you're returning a value.

Comment: @Neutrino no, as Dave Newton says its one of the very rare cases where it matters, which is why (for better or worse) its the example everyone always gives of why ASI is design flaw.

Comment: @DaveNewton perhaps ironically (given the OPs question) whitespace matters more if you leave out the semi-colons: specifically you can't start a line with `([{` without causing issues.

Comment: @JaredSmith Well yeah, if you leave out semi-colons then you're relying more on the ASI rules, kind of by definition.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, in JavaScript you have to write inline the return statement.

```
return 
{
    ...
}
```

Will be interpreted as:

```
return;
{        /********
    ...  * Error *
}        ********/
```

---

The real solution would be to stop "resisting" to JavaScript synthax (*it is cool, I swear!*), but maybe you will find this syntax more readable:

```
app.directive
(
  'alertable',
  function()
  {
    let result = { // set result
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs)
      {
        element.bind
        (
          'click',
          function()
          {
            alert(attrs.alertable);
          }
        );
      }
    };
    return result; // return it
  }
);
```

Comment: Imo significant whitespace in a brace delimitted language is about the least cool thing imaginable :)

Comment: @Neutrino The 25 years of C++ are talking... ;P. JavaScript may seem disorganized at first, but I think this is a question of habits!

Answer (score -2):

To minimize the amount of changes in code, only add a return variable assignment after `return`.

```
app.directive
(
  'alertable',
  function()
  {
    return result = 
    {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs)
      {
        element.bind
        (
          'click',
          function()
          {
            alert(attrs.alertable);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This creates (or overwrites!) a global variable `result` as a side effect.

Answer (score -3):

This is because javascript intelligently (or not so intelligently) predicts semicolon placement, so your above code when interpreted, looks like this:

```js
app.directive
(
  'alertable',
  function()
  {
    return; // <---- Notice the semicolon being inserted automatically.
    {
```

Essentially, your function is being entered, and exited immediately.

People have different coding styles. Many languages allow you to get creative with the appearance of your code, however sadly javascript is not one of those languages.

Comment: Yes, OP knows. That isn't the question.