# Can I easily get an overview of external variables in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, scope, lint

I'd like to be able to get an overview of variables used within my functions, that are not defined within that function nor arguments of that function. So essentially all variables with a scope outside the function they are used in.

I'm using eslint, I was hoping something would be available for it but I can't find it. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Those are also known as [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but browsers developer console, does gives `Scope` panel where you can access those variables

Comment: A linter only bugs you about undeclared (possibly global) variables, it doesn't provide a listing. (You could copy your function into a standalone file and try to lint that - with the right environment settings, the linter should warn about all variables not declared in the function).

Comment: @Bergi exactly, my config allows for spotting undefineds, but doesn't know about where the definition really is. I'm hoping to find a solution that can actually highlight free variables without leaving my IDE.

Comment: @JasperKennis I think [scope coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882241/is-crockford-style-context-coloring-implemented-in-any-code-editor) is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @Bergi That's great! It's not entirely what I meant, all I want is a flag for every variable that is scoped outside the function it lives in, but from the looks of what you're linking to, that could be derived from this scope colouring and isn't there yet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JasperKennis But that would just flag every variable which has a different color than the background - not particularly helpful. You'd want to know from *which* scope it comes.

Comment: @Bergi Well my thought is mostly to reduce the number of shared variables to a minimum, recently I find myself writing logic with shared vars way to much. Utils should be whitelisted, so really only variables carrying data between functions should light up. So I'm looking for a quality safeguard more then an analytical tool really, I think it could be helpful. Maybe the fact that it doesn't exist indicates otherwise xD

Comment: @JasperKennis Using outer-scoped variables is not bad as long as they are constants :-) To improve code quality, do less mutations and return new values instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of Ecma script tools to analyze variable/functions scopes that may be usefult for your needs:

https://github.com/estools/escope

Or you can use the scope inspectors of your browser of choice to inspect the scope of funcionts when you run the code in debug mode.